# azure deployment error using python 3.4 flask app

Tags: python, azure, flask, deployment

I am attempting to install a simple flask app to Azure. The app has an index page with a button that launches another page that issues a REST call. It deploys but gets a 500 error when I hit it from a Chrome browser. I get the "The page cannot be displayed....
I'm new to Azure but I have pushed a single page app that works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The errors in the git push follows:

> remote:   Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
>   remote:   Running setup.py (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\MarkupSafe\setup.py) egg_info for package MarkupSafe
>   remote:
>   remote: Installing collected packages: Flask, itsdangerous, Jinja2, Werkzeug, click, MarkupSafe
>   remote:   Running setup.py install for itsdangerous
>   remote:
>   remote:     warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs_build'
>   remote: .
>   remote:*  Error compiling 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\Jinja2\jinja2\asyncfilters.py'...
>   remote:   File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\Jinja2\jinja2\asyncfilters.py", line 7
>   remote:     async def auto_to_seq(value):
>   remote:             ^
>   remote: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   remote: 
>   remote: * Error compiling 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\Jinja2\jinja2\asyncsupport.py'...
>   remote:   File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\Jinja2\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 22
>   remote:     async def concat_async(async_gen):
>   remote:             ^
>   remote: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   remote: 
>   remote:   Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe
>   remote:

Comment: Code using the `async` statement requires at least Python 3.5.